# Extracting parameter of distribution function from string in R

Tags: r, string, character, gsub

I have a list of strings which contain  characters of  such as "dgamma(x,0.5,0.1)"
How  identify the parameters on this string? , in other word, how I get the numeric values, x=0.5 and y = 0.1?

I try this:

```
pp= "dgamma(x,0.5,0.1)"
large <- nchar(pp)
v = rep(NA, large)
for (i in 1:large) {
    v[i] <- substr(pp, start = i, stop = i)
}
grepl("\\d", v)
```

I can identify when there are numbers, but I do not know how to extract

(the method must work at any value in the parameters)

Thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to properly parse a string of R code, you can use the built in parser

```
expr <- parse(text=pp)[[1]]
```

And then you can extract all the parameters with

```
as.list(expr)[-1]
# [[1]]
# x
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0.5
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 0.1
```

in this case `x` does not equal 0.5. Those are two separate parameters. The 0.5 and 0.1 are the shape and rate parameters specifically. If you knew it was always going to be `dgamma` and wanted to get the names you could do

```
mcall <- match.call(dgamma, expr)
mcall$shape
# [1] 0.5 
mcall$rate
# [1] 0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using `sub`:

```
x <- "dgamma(x,0.5,0.1)"
sub("[^(]+\\([^,]+,\\s*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?),\\s*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\)", "\\1", x)
[1] "0.5"
sub("[^(]+\\([^,]+,\\s*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?,\\s*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\)", "\\1", x)
[1] "0.1"
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank, yes it works but I have problems when it is integers number , would I know how to adjust it for any real number?

Comment: @albert I edited my answer to allow for integers as well.